# Can't create a folder in a custom list

Tags: folder, list

I'm trying to create folders in a set of custom lists I've created. However, when I try to do this, the New Folder button in the Ribbon is disabled. I read up on the matter; and this lead me to look to enable folder creation in List Settings -> Advance Settings. However, there doesn't seem to be an option to enable folder creation on the page. It shouldn't be a permission related issue; as I created the lists; and I'm also an admin on the farm.

I could use a document library; but we will not be uploading documents to the list; so this is more then I need.

What are my options, or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 1):

Folders are not available in all list templates. These list types do not support folders: Tasks, Calendar, Discussion, Survey and Wiki.

If you used the Custom List template, then you should have the folders option available.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try to disable it and then re-enable it.  Once it is enabled in the advanced settings on my sites I can create the folder.

Comment: -1 The question already states that the option to enable/disable folder creation is not present in the Advanced Settings of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add the folder content type to your list definition ? (0x0120 from memory)

Answer (score 0):

In Advance settings of the list make sure you have selected

Make "New Folder" command available?  = yes

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but to date, very relevant as this is one or the only way to do security trimming around list items, without breaking your information into multiple lists.

Although not straight forward, you can:

- Within the List settings, go into advanced and allow creation of new folders
- Even after adding this and creating a new folder, it won't show in your list so you need to add the folder into the URL (https://contoso.sharepoint.com/lists/A/Folder1/) to
- get the link for creating a "New" list item into that specific folder https://contoso.sharepoint.com/lists/A/NewForm...?source=.......Folder1/. Then
- through a page you add links to input the data in the correct place, and
- finalize by modifying the "View" for the list to "Show all items without folders" to see all items, as if you don't go into the folders which are not shown, you won't see the items within them.

Once you've done this steps you have to add the special permissions (if desired) which are not straight forward either.

- Go into the list settings, set permissions for this list, this will give you the link that should look something like this (.../_layouts/15/user.aspx?obj=%7B233130C4-4C35-4500-8352-C9F6F22081BF%7D,list&List=%7B233130C4-4C35-4500-8352-C9F6F22081BF%7D)
- Change this specific part ",list&List" to ",#,listitem&List" and replace the # with your list item/folder (If you export into excel it will be easier to find the # of the folder you want to set the specific permissions).

Hopefully this is helpful.

The most important aspect is the user training, make it clear to them that they can't add information in the root of the list, or better yet, make the root read only for everyone and that will take care of the "New" button and ensure that they only add new items through the links.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to list setting page -> Advanced Settings – from this page under the “Folders” section change the “Make “New Folder” Command available?” to “Yes” by default this setting will be “No”.

[image: Create Folder in SharePoint List]

Output:

[image: Create Folder in SharePoint List2]

More details on the below article:

[How to create folder in SharePoint Custom List?](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/how-to-create-folder-in-sharepoint-custom-list/)

**Notes:**
**Folders are not available in all list templates:**

Folders are not available in all list templates. The below list types do not support folders:

- Tasks,
- Calendar,
- Discussion,
- Survey and
- Wiki.